# How to store php page name in variable?

Tags: php, variables

I have a php page (running locally):

```
http://localhost/webpagefolder/home.php
```

When a different page is clickedon the URL changes to reflect it. So it now becomes:

```
http://localhost/webpagefolder/home.php?here=delivery
```

because I have selected the delivery page.

How would I store the part after the = in a variable?

Something like `$name = delivery` (or whatever is displayed after the `=`)

Thanks in advance

Comment: pasre location.search into parts

Comment: woould that be in javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PHP all the GET-variables are stored in the `$_GET` super global. In your example `$_GET['here']` should contain 'delivery'.

Comment: If an answer fixes your problem, you should mark it as "Accepted answer" (below the votes to the left here)